# Subfield of $\mathbb C$ with certain degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. then, is there a subfield of $\mathbb C$ such that $[\mathbb C:K]$= $n$ ?

if $n$ = 1,2, then answer is yes. But I don't know if $n$ is larger than 2.

How do I proceed more?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202072/finiteness-of-the-algebraic-closure?s=3|0.8198

Comment: Thanks. That means any subfield K of C is of [C:K] = 1 or 2 or infinity, am i right?